# How to mark significant values of correlation test in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am working on a project which requires me to utilize netcdf data to create correlation coefficient maps between two variables. After discussing this with a cohort, we determined that the maps would be far more valuable if we could overlay a "+" over statistically significant cells. However, since I utilized netcdf data for the United States, there were several NA values and I had to use `cor` instead of `cor.test`. So now I have maps that have coefficients, but the significance values are non existent. Would I need to make separate maps for the significance values or is there anyway to combine the two? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: If needed I can upload my code, but since the nature of this question is more akin to brainstorming, I didn't think it was necessary to include it.

Comment: `NA`s don't preclude the use of `cor.test()`. What does `getOption("na.action")` return?

Comment: It returns an: [1] "na.omit", is that normal? I was under the influence that if the data set possessed a large amount of NA values cor.test could not be utilized. Would I just need to make room for all of the results within an array?

Comment: Hope it isn't wrong to bump, but I really need an answer to this.

Comment: Sorry for the delay--can you post a minimal example of your data and a better explanation of why you don't think you should use `cor.test`